# Null pointer exception only While loading data from Data loader (bulk upload)

Tags: trigger

I am facing issue "Null pointer exception Attempt to deference a null object" while loading data from data loader.
But when creating individual record it is not throwing any Error.

Here is my code :

```
 Map<String, Account> acmap = new Map<String,Account>();
 Set<ID> accIds = new Set<Id>();

List<customObject> cblist =  new List<customObject>();
    for(Account acc : [Select ID,Name,Number__C,example__r.ID from Account Where Number__C IN: numSet]){

        acmap.put(acc.Number__C, acc );   
        accIds.add(acc.example__r.ID); 

    }
 Map<id,Contact> mapcontact = new map<id,Contact>();
    for(Contact con : [Select ID,Name,AccountId  from Contact where AccountId IN: accIds])
    {
        mapContact.put(con.AccountId ,con);
    }

    for(CustomObject cb : Trigger.New){


            if(acmap.containskey(cb.Number__c)){
                cb.LookupAcc__c = acmap.get(cb.Number__c).example__r.ID;           


            }

            // While inserting the contact I am getting that error
              if(mapContact.containskey(acmap.get(cb.Number__c).example__r.ID)){
                     cb.LookupContact__c  = mapContact.get(acmap.get(kyc.Customer_Number__c).example__r.Id).ID;
                    } 
        cblist.add(cb);

    }
    insert cblist;
```

Comment: acmap may not contain that number; you should not assume that it does. Also, `example__r.Id` is the same as `example__c`, which would be the preferred way of accessing the Id from a performance perspective. Also, I'm pretty sure you're doing something wrong if you're inserting records in Trigger.new. You should be getting exceptions all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
Map<String, Account> acmap = new Map<String,Account>();
Set<ID> accIds = new Set<Id>();

List<customObject> cblist =  new List<customObject>();
    for(Account acc : [Select ID,Name,Number__C,example__c from Account Where Number__C IN: numSet]){

        acmap.put(acc.Number__C, acc );   
        accIds.add(acc.example__c); 

    }
 Map<id,Contact> mapcontact = new map<id,Contact>();
    for(Contact con : [Select ID,Name,AccountId  from Contact where AccountId IN: accIds])
    {
        mapContact.put(con.AccountId ,con);
    }

    for(CustomObject cb : Trigger.New){


        if(acmap.containskey(cb.Number__c)){
            cb.LookupAcc__c = acmap.get(cb.Number__c).example__c;           

            // While inserting the contact I am getting that error
            if(mapContact.containskey(cb.LookupAcc__c){
               cb.LookupContact__c  = mapContact.get(cb.LookupAcc__c).ID;
            } 
        }
        //If this is Insert event, you dont have to add them to a list 
        //cblist.add(cb);

    }
    //
    //insert cblist;
```